# Call a function inside ngFor in angular2

Tags: angular

Hello I am using Angular2 and wanted to fetch the server and get some values for each ID I get inside ngFor.

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items">
  <span> here call a function that do something with 'item' and return something new <span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a weird requirement. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer For example, generate a display name of the item properties in some complex way. That's not weird at all.

Comment: Do it in code and assign it to each `item` and then just use it inside `*ngFor`. Such function calls from template bindings are discouraged.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer any chance you could share an example of the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: this is not a weird requirement at all manipulate data on item create is obvious task not implement by angular team.

Comment: yes, it's not a weird requirement, rather it's to manipulate data without separate loop

Answer (score 15):

You can make use of custom directive to call the method for each iteration:

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Input, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onCreate]'
})
export class OnCreate {

  @Output() onCreate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {      
     this.onCreate.emit('dummy'); 
  } 

}
```

and then you can use it in your *ngFor to call the method in your component:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="item" (onCreate)="yourMethod(item)"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

in Your component you can call this method as:

```
yourMethod(item){
   console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Is there an update needed for this code to be compatible with Angular 6? I can not get this to work as is. The function never gets called. I had to rename some things to make TSLint allow my app to compile as well. `OnCreate`/`onCreate` need to be renamed to `NgForOnCreateDirective`/`ngForOnCreateDirective` and the selector has to be prefixed with app, so I changed it to `appNgForOnCreate`

Comment: @Routhinator, does this sample works on Angular 5? cause the called function doesn't working. PS: I changed onCreate by CallFnDirective and the selector as '[appCallFn]'.

Answer (score 10):

Doesn't sound very good , however , the simplest way :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span data-dummy="{{myFunction()}}" > here call a function that do something with 'item' and return something new <span>
</div>
```

Proper way :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[runDummyFunc]'
})
export class runDummyFunc {

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {      
     this.runDummyFunc()
  } 

}


<div *ngFor="let item in items">
    <span [runDummyFunc]="myFunction" > here call a function that do something with 'item' and return something new <span>
</div>
```

In your class :

```
      myFunction = ():void=>{

         console.log('whatever');
      }
```

Comment: using interpolation to call a function is not an authentic way, as it will be called multiple times due to `ngOnChanges`. @xe4me

Comment: @BhushanGadekar , I know this is not a good way ,  that's why I've said doesn't sound good , but this is what he wants , and he can easily create a variable like fire_once and set it to true if it's called once , any way , this is not a good way

Answer (score 7):

How about **changing data before it comes to `*ngFor`** in **Typescript** itself,

```
this.items.forEach((item,index)=>{
  item=this.func(item,index);
})

func(item,index):string{
    return item+ String(index); //do whatever you wish to do.
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this inside a subscribe function, however I could not find a way to access `this.newArray` that I was trying to create in the forEach. Can you update this with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Better do such function calls on each item in ngOnInit in a subscription, and then they should be displayed with *ngFor after transformation.

and change:

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items">
```

to

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
```

Comment: will u provide some code for the way u suggested above??

Answer (score 1):

The template is not the place to do that, you want to get your data in the component code.  Sounds like you want to use something like `flatMap` of an observable, which lets you return another observable for each item in the source observable.  This could be the returns of an http api call or whatever [(**fiddle**)](https://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/s5mm8oqf/1):

```
var ids = ["a", "d", "c"];
var lookupValues = { "a": 123, "b": 234, "c": 345, "d": 456 };

// given an id
function fakeApiCall(id) {
  // given an id, return an observable with one entry: an object consisting
  // of an 'id' property with that id value and a 'lookup' property with the
  // value from lookupValues for that id
  return Rx.Observable.just({ id: id, lookup: lookupValues[id] });
}

var o1 = Rx.Observable.from(ids); // 'a, d, c

var o2 = o1.flatMap(x => {
  // here we get each value from o1, so we do an api call and return
  // an observable from each that will have the values in that
  // observable combined with all others to be sent to o2
  return fakeApiCall(x);
});

o2.subscribe(x => {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(x) + "<br/>");
});

// result:
// {"id":"a","lookup":123}
// {"id":"d","lookup":456}
// {"id":"c","lookup":345}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use trackBy:

```
@Component({
selector:'heroes',
template: `
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackHero" >
            <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`})

export class Heroes {
    heroes = HEROES;

    trackHero(index, hero) {
        console.log(hero);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can pass in the item to a function along with an event variable like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items">
  <span (click)="functionCall($event, item)"> <span>
</div>
```

And then grab that item in your class like this:

```
functionCall(event, item): void {
  console.log('item clicked:", item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write an another "ngFor" in between span tag in component.html

```
 <div *ngFor="let item in items">  
    <span *ngFor="let new of filterItems(item)"> {{new.anyAttribute}} </span>
 </div>
```

in component.ts
if you want to filter item

```
filterItems(item) {
  let filterArray:any=[];
  return filterArray.filter(x => x.anyAttribute == item.anyAttribute);
}
```

if you want to return an array in item

```
filterItems(item){
   return item.Array //Array is an array in item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Component({
    selector:'heroes',
    template: `
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackHero" >
                <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
`
})
export class Heroes {

    heroes = HEROES;

    trackHero(index, hero) {
        console.log(hero);
        return hero ? hero.id : undefined;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this may be the actual answer to the question in the title. `trackBy` caches the data in each iteration and is probably where we should work logic on that iteration.