# Angular: Get current index in ngFor

Tags: angular

I have following angular:

```xml
<div class="test" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
    {{item}}
</div>

<div class="function_div" (click)="test(i);">Test Button </div>
```

then in `.ts`,

```ts
export class test{
   
  test(){
     console.log(i);
  }
  
}
```

I want to get a variable with the current index number.

How would I go about so that I can get the current index?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you going to get index? What is the current index outside `ngFor` scope in your opinion?

Comment: here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322829/how-to-use-track-by-inside-ngfor-angular-2

Comment: So, I am trying to get the index of the ngFor in order to do a comparison to array of data before triggering another function. For example, the `test()` function will be triggered when I click a button, then it will check the current `index`, and do something with it.

Comment: There is no "current" index unless you call from within the `<div class="test">`. Outside of that div, your "loop" is complete, you just have the `data` array.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I understand.

Comment: @steveKim , please also read the note on my answer :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**As per OP's comment on question :**

> So, I am trying to get the index of the ngFor in order to do a
> comparison to array of data before triggering another function. For
> example, the test() function will be triggered when I click a button,
> then it will check the current index, and do something with it.

**You should do it like :**

```xml
<div class="test" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
    // In your case this line should be within ngFor loop
    <div class="function_div" (click)="test(i);">Test Button </div>
    {{item}}
</div>
```

---

> **Note : Never call function like :**
>
> `{{ test(i) }}` // this will be executed each time anything changes in
> loop

Comment: Yeah, I understand about your last comment. I will be careful. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question. What would be the best way to call the `test()` function only when the ngFor is done iterating? Thus, I can see the last index number.

Comment: @steveKim , Great , coz sometime it causes big issues , Happy Coding BTW

Comment: If you want to get last index then you can use array.length function that you can access also outside of the ngFor

Answer (score 7):

You couls alwasy go the simple way, like that:

```
    <div *ngFor =" let item of items; let i = index">

          {{ i }} {{ item }}

    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why you just not..

```
<div class="test" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
    {{ test(i) }}
</div>


export class test{

  test(i: number){
     console.log(i);
  }

}
```

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that the function (test()) will be used outside of `<div class="test">`, thus I need another way around it.

Comment: @steveKim -- The index only exists while you're iterating. If you exit the iteration, it does not exist -- hence Kenry's suggestion.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own directive to get the current index on every function call through `*ngFor`. You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788085/2621579).